# Django cms 3.4.1 admin dlogo

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-cms

I want to change django admin logo.
I'm using django cms 3.4.1.

I tried to find logos in:

```
cms/templates/cms/

 /media/cms/images/cms_toolbar.png
```

All I found was favicon.jpg in `myproject/static/django_cms_style/img.`
I deleted it, but doesnt work.

I tried with css too. I hide one logo, but logo in admin page and login page, they are still there.

```
div.cms .cms-toolbar-item-logo a:before {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CMS uses another app for it's admin styling called [djangocms-admin-style](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-admin-style). and the top of admin can be customised by overriding the `branding.html` file seen here;

https://github.com/divio/djangocms-admin-style/blob/master/djangocms_admin_style/templates/admin/inc/branding.html

So if you create `admin/inc/branding.html` in your project's templates directory you will be able to change the content.