# How to make djangocms-admin-style logo dynamic?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-cms

I'm using django-cms admin style. I managed to change the default DjangoCMS logo, by following the solution mentioned here:
[Django cms 3.4.1 admin dlogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788284/django-cms-3-4-1-admin-dlogo)

Now the logo is a static one, but I want it to be dynamic, meaning it should get the image path from the database, where the location is stored.

As these admin pages are not render through views.py, I'm not able to sent the querysets to it.

Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `context_processors` we can do this.

first need to get this: https://github.com/divio/djangocms-admin-style/blob/master/djangocms_admin_style/templates/admin/inc/branding.html

branding.html file must be put inside **templates** folder under **admin/inc** folder, so the structure will be like this `templates/admin/inc/branding.html`

now suppose through context_processor we got `company_logo`, that holds the logo url from database.

then in branding.html `<div id="header-logo">` would be like:

```
<div id="header-logo">
    {% if company_logo %}
        <a href="/"><img src="{{ company_logo.url }}" style="height:inherit;"></a>
    {% else %}
        <a class="icon-logo" href="/"><span>django CMS</span></a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```